# What is the difference between the following code

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie. I have some basic doubts. Please someone clarify it for me so that I can improve my java skills and will be able to help others in this forum.

I have 2 lines of code. I just want to know the difference between these 2 lines of code.

```
1)Date sbmEndDate = new Date(getSystemDateTime().getYear(), mnth, 1);
```

and

```
2)DateTime cmSbmbillDttm = (DateTime)cmSbmQuery.firstRow();
```

My question is: in the first line we have used `new` keyword, but in the second line we have not used any keyword. What is the difference and please someone explain me the importance of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date sbmEndDate = new Date(getSystemDateTime().getYear(), mnth, 1);
```

The above code uses a `Date` constructor to instantiate a new `Date` object. This object is assigned to the `Date` variable `sbmEndDate`.

Whereas,

```
DateTime cmSbmbillDttm = (DateTime)cmSbmQuery.firstRow();
```

Here, we are calling a member function `firstRow` of the variable `cmSbmQuery`. This function returns an object whose type cannot be inferred from the above code only. This object is then type-casted to `DateTime`, which is then assigned to a variable `cmSbmbillDttm` of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You used `new`  is to create new Instance (also called as object) of `Date` class.

And `cmSbmQuery.firstRow()` will give you an instance  of `DateTime`  class (or its super class), so you don't want to use `new` keyword there.

For more details , you can refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
cmSbmQuery.firstRow()
```

this line returns you DateTime object, which is after casting assigned to cmSbmbillDttm.

Answer (score 0):

> first line we have used "new" keyword but in the second line we have not used any keyword

1) In first line creates **new Date object** with by calling [Date constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public Date(int year, int month, int date)
```

- [`new` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.

2) Second line just returns the `DateTime` object reference by calling `cmSbmQuery.firstRow()`.
**Here is no new object created instead the same object reference is returned.**